# Azure Devops python script failing

Tags: python, azure-devops

I have an Azure Devops pipeline with some python tasks that were working until today. They haven't been modified in any way recently but my builds have started failing intermittently today.

Here is my pipeline:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    exclude:
      - '*'

pool:
  name: 'Azure Pipelines'
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build
    variables:
      buildConfiguration: "Release"
      buildPlatform: "AnyCPU"
    jobs:
    - job:
      steps:
      - task: UsePythonVersion@0
        inputs:
          versionSpec: '3.7'
          architecture: 'x64'    
      - script: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel
```

The script task now fails about 50% of the time with the following error:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.10/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages (21.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.10/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages (47.1.0)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wheel (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for wheel
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this? It looks like it has something to do with the `hostedtoolcache` but I have no idea what to do about it.

Comment: Your requirement `wheel` version is not present in python repository. Try to install it locally with the same configurations. Nothin related with Azure Devops tasks or hosts.